# My silverlight application is still trying to connect to localhost after being published to a remote server

Tags: silverlight, iis-7, silverlight-4.0, crossdomain.xml, clientaccesspolicy.xml

I'm developing a silverlight application that uses a web service.  It works just fine when I run it on my local machine but when I publish it to a remote server, it fails because it is looking for a a crossdomain.xml policy at localhost:4689 instead of the websites root directory.  How do I fix this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The problem may be in the file ServicReferences.ClientConfig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the service reference, the host--in your case, localhost--is included as part of the generated code, and is the default endpoint when you create the service client on the Silverlight end with no constructor parameters.

Use the constructor overload of the service client class that accepts a `Uri` parameter to specify the correct hostname (and path to the .svc file) on your production server.

Comment: My web service is a .asmx file do I need to rename it to a .svc too?

Comment: No, sorry -- I meant asmx. svc is for WCF services, which is what I've been using lately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your ServiceReferences.ClientConfig because when you deploy your project it's still using the endpoint address of your local computer.